# Xpath text between tags

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Any idea how i would get the text between 2 tags using Xpath code? specifically the 3, bd, 1, ba.

```
<p class="MuiTypography-root RoofCard__RoofCardNameStyled-niegej-8 hukPZu MuiTypography-body1" xpath="1">

<span class="NumberFormatWithStyle__NumberFormatStyled-sc-1yvv7lw-0 jVQRaZ inline-block md">$65,000</span></p>

**"3" == $0
" bd, " == $0
"1" == $0
" ba | " == $0**

<span class="NumberFormatWithStyle__NumberFormatStyled-sc-1yvv7lw-0 jVQRaZ inline-block md" xpath="1">926</span>
```

tried:

Comment: *tried*? Where is your trials?

Answer (score 1):

In fact from your sample that's a simple `text()` node after `p`:

```
//p/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

but of course you'll need to parse it. This will return almost that you need:

```
values = response.xpath('//p/following-sibling::text()[1]').re(r'"([^"]+)"')
```